# Regex match Function parameters

Tags: python, regex

```
select\[([^\s]*(?<param>[a-z0-9]+)[^,\s]*)*\]
```

attempting to load capture group with (numerics or alpha-num options) from comma separated params ignoring leading/trailing whitespace of each param but preserving space between words (ie "two words").

```
select[  1, 22 ,word,      two words    ]
```

to become:

```
param1: "1"
param2: "22"
param3: "word"
param4: "two words"
```

[RegEx101](https://regex101.com/r/a0ab0Q/7)

once thats sorted, would like to handle optional single quotes ' around parameters.

Thanks for the consideration

Comment: It is not possible to capture all the values with a repeated capturing group. Only the last value will be kept in the Group memory buffer. The approach you follow won't work. Unless you use it in C#/.NET (or PyPi regex Python module).

Comment: Please consider `kiki` / `kiki-re` - that is done with python. Under Linux you can install it from appropriate packaging system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another one for engines that support `\G`:

```
(?:\G(?!\A)|select\[)        # look for the last match or select[
\s*                          # whitespaces, optional and greedy
((?:(?!(?:[ ]{2,}|\]|,)).)+) # not overrunning two consecutive spaces, ] or ,
\s*                          # another greedy whitespace
(?:,|\])                     # , or ]
```

Highjacking your demo: **https://regex101.com/r/a0ab0Q/8**

---

You might want to erase whitespaces on both sides which could be done (using ie `Python`):

```
import regex as re
rx = re.compile(r'''
        (?:\G(?!\A)|select\[)
        \s*
        ((?:(?!(?:[ ]{2,}|\]|,)).)+)
        \s*
        (?:,|\])
''', re.VERBOSE)

params = [match.group(1).strip()
          for match in rx.finditer(string)]
print(params)
# ['1', '22', 'word', 'two words']
```

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify the programming language, but for `python` you can use:

```
import re
string = re.sub(r"select\[\s+|\]", "", "select[  1, 22 ,word,      two words    ]")
final, n = "", 1
for p in [p.strip() for p in string.split(",")]:
    final += 'param{}:"{}", '.format(n,p)
    n += 1
print final.rstrip(", ")
# param1:"1", param2:"22", param3:"word", param4:"two words"
```

---

[Python Demo](https://ideone.com/WTqKLE)

Answer (score 1):

C# for giggles:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        Regex regex = new Regex(@"[a-zA-Z0-9 ]*(?=\s*[,\]])");

        string test = @"select[  1, 22 ,word,      two words    ]";

        MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(test);

        IEnumerable<string> items = matches.Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value.Trim());

        items.ToList().ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Perl solution:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "select[  1, 22 ,word,      two words    ]";

if ($str =~ m{ \b select \[ \s* }xg) {
    my @param;
    while ($str =~ m{ ( \w+ (?: \s+ \w+ )* | ' [^']* ' ) \s* }xg) {
        push @param, $1;
        $str =~ m{ , \s* }xgc
            or last;
    }
    if ($str =~ m{ \] }xg) {
        print "$_\n" for @param;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
1
22
word
two words
```

It tries to validate the input a bit (i.e. it doesn't produce output for malformed strings) and it already parses single-quoted parameters.

Comment: This question is taged Python, you answered in Perl. What a coincidence!

Comment: @revo The `python` tag was added a full four days after I posted my answer. You might notice that one of the other answers mentions this explicitly, and a third answer uses C#.